# quality destroy and getting dotes effect on gif when converting Video to GIF using FFMPEG, how to get clear gif?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, ffmpeg, gif

In Android I want to convert mp4 video to gif file,

I'm converting this using FFMPEG library and getting successfully converted gif. there is issue when gif converted there are some other color effect apply and show dots on gif.

below commands I have already try for this convert process

```
1)  cmd =  arrayOf("-y","-i", path, destPath)


2)  cmd =  arrayOf(
               "-i",
               path,
               "-vf",
               "fps=10,scale=500:-1:flags=lanczos",
               "-pix_fmt",
               "rgb24",
              destPath
          )

3)  cmd =  arrayOf(
              "-y",
              "-i",
              path,
              "-r",
              "15",
              destPath
            )
```

Comment: See [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031/)

Comment: GIF only uses maximum 256 colours per frame. You won't get film quality from GIF format. The dots are called "dithering" where the encoder tries to create a blending effect  on color gradients (color blending from one to another). See if these artickles help you: **(1)** [High Quality GIFs in FFmpeg](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html) and **(2)** [Optimizing GIF with FFmpeg](https://cassidy.codes/blog/2017/04/25/ffmpeg-frames-to-gif-optimization/) especially the `paletteGen` might help you get better colours.